# SQL convert Seconds to Minutes to Hours

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2012

i have an SQL Query that counts the total amount of conversations with Voice-over-IP.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Aantal gesprekken'
,FromUri AS 'Medewerker'
,SUM(DATEDIFF(hour,InviteTime,EndTime)) AS 'Uren'
,SUM(DATEDIFF(minute,InviteTime,EndTime)) AS 'Minuten'
,SUM(DATEDIFF(second,InviteTime,EndTime)) AS 'Secondes'
   FROM [LcsCDR].[dbo].[SessionDetailsView]
WHERE FromUri LIKE '%robert%'
AND (CAST([InviteTime] AS date)) BETWEEN '2012-12-27' AND '2013-01-28'
AND MediaTypes = '16'
GROUP BY FromUri
```

SQL Server 2012 gives this result: Number, employee, hours, minutes and seconds.

```
302 robert  11  518 31316
```

But i need to get this result: 28 hours, 19 minutes and 56 seconds. I calculated that the reguler / 60 way, but how can i do this in SQL that i get a accurate result?!

In forward, many thanks!

Comment: Why don't you calculate the time differences all in the same format (seconds for instance), add them all together and then convert that value into your hours, minutes and seconds?

Comment: That worked, did not thought about that :) Thanks!

Comment: @steoleary, could you please add the solution to the end of this question? This might help other people who are facing the same issue, wouldn't this? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Steoleary i have managed a solution

```
DECLARE @SecondsToConvert int
SET @SecondsToConvert = (SELECT (SUM(DATEDIFF(hour,InviteTime,EndTime) * 3600) + SUM(DATEDIFF(minute,InviteTime,EndTime) * 60) + SUM(DATEDIFF(second,InviteTime,EndTime) * 1)) AS [Seconds] 
 FROM [LcsCDR].[dbo].[SessionDetailsView]
WHERE FromUri LIKE '%robert%'
AND (CAST([InviteTime] AS date)) BETWEEN '2012-12-27' AND '2013-01-28'
AND MediaTypes = '16'
GROUP BY FromUri)

-- Declare variables
 DECLARE @Hours int
 DECLARE @Minutes int
 DECLARE @Seconds int

-- Set the calculations for hour, minute and second
SET @Hours = @SecondsToConvert/3600
SET @Minutes = (@SecondsToConvert % 3600) / 60
SET @Seconds = @SecondsToConvert % 60

SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Aantal gesprekken'
,FromUri AS 'Medewerker'
,@Hours AS 'Uren' ,@Minutes AS 'Minuten' , @Seconds AS 'Seconden'
 FROM [LcsCDR].[dbo].[SessionDetailsView]
WHERE FromUri LIKE '%robert%'
AND (CAST([InviteTime] AS date)) BETWEEN '2012-12-27' AND '2013-01-28'
AND MediaTypes = '16'
GROUP BY FromUri
```

As a result, i now get the accurate time.

```
302 robert  28  19  56
```

28 hours, 19 minutes and 56 seconds, just like it should be :)

Answer (score 1):

Try Like below query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Aantal gesprekken',FromUri AS 'Medewerker',                
concat(
  floor(SUM(DATEDIFF(second,InviteTime,EndTime))/3600),":",   //Hrs
  floor(SUM(DATEDIFF(second,InviteTime,EndTime))/60)%60,":",  //Mins
  SUM(DATEDIFF(second,InviteTime,EndTime))%60                 //Secs
  ) as Total_Hrs
   FROM [LcsCDR].[dbo].[SessionDetailsView]
WHERE FromUri LIKE '%robert%'
AND (CAST([InviteTime] AS date)) BETWEEN '2012-12-27' AND '2013-01-28'
AND MediaTypes = '16'
GROUP BY FromUri
```